# REGEXP_REPLACE string compare

Tags: oracle

in oracle I would like to compare 2 string as below

> 19.12.XX.11 = 19.12.YY.11

I have tried with the below one but it only replaces the 1st character only

```
select REGEXP_REPLACE('19.12.1.11' ,'.', 'x', 4, 4  ) 
  from dual;
```

Comment: `LIKE` operator in this case will do the job just fine.  For example: `where ipaddr like '19.12.%.11'`

Comment: @NicholasKrasnov you comment itself an answer

Answer (score 0):

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE ipaddresses ( addr1, addr2 ) AS
  SELECT '19.12.0.11', '19.12.1.11' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query**:

```
SELECT addr1,
       addr2,
       CASE TO_NUMBER( REGEXP_SUBSTR( addr1, '\d+', 1, 1 ) )
         WHEN TO_NUMBER( REGEXP_SUBSTR( addr2, '\d+', 1, 1 ) )
         THEN 'Match'
         ELSE 'No Match'
         END AS Byte1,
       CASE TO_NUMBER( REGEXP_SUBSTR( addr1, '\d+', 1, 2 ) )
         WHEN TO_NUMBER( REGEXP_SUBSTR( addr2, '\d+', 1, 2 ) )
         THEN 'Match'
         ELSE 'No Match'
         END AS Byte2,
       CASE TO_NUMBER( REGEXP_SUBSTR( addr1, '\d+', 1, 3 ) )
         WHEN TO_NUMBER( REGEXP_SUBSTR( addr2, '\d+', 1, 3 ) )
         THEN 'Match'
         ELSE 'No Match'
         END AS Byte3,
       CASE TO_NUMBER( REGEXP_SUBSTR( addr1, '\d+', 1, 4 ) )
         WHEN TO_NUMBER( REGEXP_SUBSTR( addr2, '\d+', 1, 4 ) )
         THEN 'Match'
         ELSE 'No Match'
         END AS Byte4
FROM   ipaddresses;
```

**Output**:

```
ADDR1      ADDR2      BYTE1    BYTE2    BYTE3    BYTE4
---------- ---------- -------- -------- -------- --------
19.12.0.11 19.12.1.11 Match    Match    No Match Match
```